# Python - Plotting vertical line

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a curve of some data that I am plotting using matplotlib.  The small value x-range of the data consists entirely of NaN values, so that my curve starts abruptly at some value of x>>0 (which is not necessarily the same value for different data sets I have).  I would like to place a vertical dashed line where the curve begins, extending from the curve, to the x axis.  Can anyone advise how I could do this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you know where the curve begins, you can just use:

`plt.plot((x1, x2), (y1, y2), 'r-')` to draw the line from the point `(x1, y1)` to the point `(x2, y2)`

Here in your case, `x1` and `x2` will be same, only `y1` and `y2` should change, as it is a straight vertical line that you want.

Comment: If I don't know where the curve begins, is there a way I can find out the position in an array of the first non-NaN values?

Comment: Yes can be done.. just use a `for` loop to find the exact position of the last `NaN` in your array. Then assuming your array is called `x`, you can use `x[12]` assuming that the last `NaN` value was found at the 12th position in your array

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you can also use [plt.vlines](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.vlines) to draw a vertical line and provided that your data is in a numpy array and not a list, you can skip the for loop to determine the first non-NaN value and make use of [np.isfinite](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isfinite.html) instead. Something like:

```
x_value = data_array[np.where(np.isfinite(data_array))[0]]
```

Depending on how many values you have to loop through to get to the first finite value each time, this may be a faster option.

Answer (score 2):

To plot vertical dashed line you have to set the same x value and make code like this (use '--' for dashed line or ':'):

```
x = 100  # line at this x position
y0 = 0   # y limits of a line
y1 = 100
plt.plot((x,x),(y0,y1),'k--')
```